# How to produce platform independent source files (which can generate project files for anyone using cmake) from a visual studio solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I know  cmake is a tool which can produce visual studio solution files from source files. I see many of c++ projects are stored in the github in that way. My problem is how create that source. Is there anyway to generate it on visual studio or anyother way.? I have created a project by using visual studio . So I have the solution file. I want to upload it in to github as a portable source which can produce project files later using cmake for anyone.

Comment: VS has some helpers see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/

Comment: Since you are into cmake (which BTW is a good thing, for the portability), why not let cmake compile and build the sources instead of the VS solution? Not many has VS and might want to build your sources too.

Comment: What is the way of producing platform independent sources from a visual studio solution? I can't figure out that.

Comment: You write `CMakeLists.txt` manually (which is not hard). However, this alone is not enough for a platform-independent solution. You also need to avoid writing platform-dependent code (calling platform-dependent library functions, using platform-dependent tricks etc.)